# Removing pseudo-selectors with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, zepto

We have styled our buttons using:

```
.button{blah}
.button:active{blah}
```

When we submit the form, we disable the buttons

```
$('#letterButtons input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

but on webkit, after they have been disabled they still "look" active because they change when clicked.

Tried this but no joy...

```
$('#letterButtons input').removeClass('button:active');
$('#letterButtons input').removeClass('button\\:active');
```

Actually after setting the tags, I remembered that we are using Zepto, so it might be a zepto problem...

Comment: Make sure your WebKit browser is the most recent version -- I'm finding some results on Google that suggest this is a resolved browser bug (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-this-a-bug-in-webkit-or-jquery-disabling-input-text-programatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using:

```
$('#letterButtons input').trigger('mouseleave');
```

But this is prone to failing if the mouse is still hovering over the element. You could also use CSS:

```
#letterButtons button[disabled]:active {
    color: #999;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: The second example worked and is very elegant.  Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$('#letterButtons input').removeClass('button');
```

it seems to me that it is 'button' that is the classname.